# Cannot access Postgres Docker container in AWS CodeBuild

Tags: postgresql, docker, aws-codebuild

I've got a simple Code Build project for a Django App and I want to start a Postgres database in a docker container for testing.

The commands are:

```
docker run --name django-test-db -d -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=djangotest -e POSTGRES_USER=configuration-service-master -e POSTGRES_DB=configuration-service postgres:12-alpine
docker exec django-test-db psql -U configuration-service-master -c \"\\dn\"
```

On my local machine everything works quite fine, but in AWS CodeBuild I'm receiving the error:

> psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server:
>   No such file or directory
>       Is the server running locally and accepting
>       connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Answer (score 2):

Try two things:

1. Connect with '-h' flag to specify host so the connection goes through TCP/IP instead of Unix Socket

   ```
   psql -h localhost -p 5432
   ```
2. Enable privileged mode on Build project:

   - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/change-project.html#change-project-console

Comment: This didn't solve the problem, but finally I found the reason for this error...
It seems that the Postgres database is not fully started yet. I added another build step in between and now it works! :-)